# Azure SQL Database: The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: azure-sql-database

Our application has been connecting to SQL Server that resides in VM and we recently, decided to migrate to Azure SQL Database. Azure SQL Database is up and running, and we are able to connect to it from SQL Management Studio on development environment.

On the production server, we change the application connection string as follow:
Data Source=my-azure-production.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=DummyDatabase;User ID=DummyUser;Password=password;Application Name=DummyApplication; MultipleActiveResultSets=True

When the application first connecting to Azure SQL, the application throw "InvalidOperationException:  Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached." (I am certain not because of connection pool issue)

When the same connection string is used on development machine, the application can connect to the database and work without issue. We run the same application on another server and we do not encounter the error too.

When the same credential is used for EF6 connection string, we get the following AggregateException:

```
Type: AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
StackTrace: at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at ......:line 86
Type: EntityException
Message: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
StackTrace: at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
at ....... :line 84
at ....... :line 97
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at ..... :line 86
Type: EntityException
Message: The underlying provider failed on Open.
StackTrace: at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
Type: EntityException
Message: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. If you are connecting to a SQL Azure database consider using SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.
StackTrace: at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
Type: SqlException
Message: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
StackTrace: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__36(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__2()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
Type: Win32Exception
Message: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
StackTrace: null
```

The same EF6 connection string do not have the issue when application is running on development machine or another server.

We believe it is environmental related issue but have no idea how to troubleshoot this error. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the Production server have outbound Internet access?

Your underlying error is "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".

That sounds a lot like a firewall completely or partially blocking the connection between the app and the endpoint in Azure.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed due to firewall in the Azure VM instead of the firewall in Azure SQL. This also documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/sql-database/sql-database-develop-direct-route-ports-adonet-v12?view=tfs-2013 (Inside: Client runs on Azure)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure SQL database connection string doesn't has the attribute `Application Name=DummyApplication;`.

Please get the correct connect string from the Azure Portal:
[image]

Try to use the new connect string to connect again. You also can reference this Azure Document [Quickstart: Use .NET and C# in Visual Studio to connect to and query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio).

Please make you have opened the firewall and allow access to Azure Service 'ON':
[image]

Add client IP and set allow access to Azure Service 'ON'
[image]

Hope this helps.